# Django: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm doing the Django 1.8 tutorial to make a Polls app:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/

I added a boolean function called was_published recently() which would return either True or False if a post was published recently.
The function is defined here under the Question class

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateField('date published')

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() -  datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text
```

In addition, I have an admin set up which displays the questions, as follows:
    from django.contrib import admin

```
from .models import Choice,Question

class ChoiceInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3


class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,                 {'fields':['question_text']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields':['pub_date'],'classes':['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInLine]
    list_display = ('question_text','pub_date','was_published_recently')


admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

However when I access the Questions part of my admin, I get an error that says:

```
TypeError at /admin/polls/question/
can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/polls/question/
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date
Exception Location: C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\venv\forumtest\polls\models.py  in was_published_recently, line 12
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\venv\Scripts\python.EXE
Python Version: 3.4.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\venv\\forumtest',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python34.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\venv\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\venv\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\venv\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Python34\\Lib',
 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 22 Jul 2015 16:30:07 -0700

Error during template rendering

In template C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\change_list.html, error at line 91
can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date


81          {% endif %}
82        {% endblock %}
83  
84        <form id="changelist-form" action="" method="post"{% if cl.formset.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %} novalidate>{% csrf_token %}
85        {% if cl.formset %}
86          <div>{{ cl.formset.management_form }}</div>
87        {% endif %}
88  
89        {% block result_list %}
90            {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
91  

  {% result_list cl %}



92            {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
93        {% endblock %}
94        {% block pagination %}{% pagination cl %}{% endblock %}
95        </form>
96      </div>
97    </div>
98  {% endblock %}
99
```

I'm using django 1.8, and I did the same tutorial with 1.7 and didn't have the same problem. I'm not sure if this problem is a bug or not.

Please let me know how I can fix this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

In the tutorial pub_date is defined as DateTimeField, using that you are comparing datetime values.

Comment: You are welcome. Btw, If in some situation you need to compare a date value against a datetime you can use [combine](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) before to compare.

Comment: got it. I'll remember to make use of it if I need it.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now().date()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
```